# Does the guest OS need updates/changes after changing the number of cores in VMware Player?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, vmware-player, multi-core

I installed ubuntu on a vm in VMware Player and forgot to change the number of cores from 1 to 8. If I change that now will the linux kernel need to be recompiled or anything like that or will it just work?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try? Did you run into a particular problem?

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and did it. I'm not having any problems with it but I have no idea if it's actually using the extra cores.

Comment: Most of the distro have pre-compiled kernels and assuming from your question, I highly doubt you're using Gentoo or any other distro that compiles packages. Your distro should pickup the new cores without any issues.

Comment: I do want to note, adding extra cores might change your licensing for the host machine and/or guest VM and/or software running on them.  For example, at the last time I checked, Oracle is licensed based on the number of cores on the *host* machine, regardless of the number of cores/slices on the guest machine.

Comment: @Ramhound And the fact that the user didn't compile the kernel themselves isn't relevant. Be helpful or stfu.

Comment: @Ramhound I wasn't being rude; I was asking you to stop being rude. Nothing you've said has contributed in any way to helping answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding CPU to the virtual machine does not require a recompile of the kernel. What may require a recompile is moving the machine to a different CPU type - for example, from an old CPU type to a new one, or from an AMD Opteron to an Intel Xeon. This kind of changes might require kernel reconfiguration to allow for the different modules that apply.

If you look at `lshw` for example, you can see how many CPU your virtual machine has. As to whether it `utilize` them or not, it depends on what you mean. You can look at your load average. If you have 1 CPU and load average is lower than 1, then you are not fully utilizing them (i.e. you are not requesting enough processing to need a full CPU). If you have 2 CPU and your load average is nearly 2, then you are fully utilizing all your CPU processing power (see for example [Unix Load Averages Explained](http://www.lifeaftercoffee.com/2006/03/13/unix-load-averages-explained/)).

Comment: Thanks! I only knew that the installation process somehow customized the kernel to the processor. I had no idea when or if reinstalling or recompiling would be necessary. I've selected this as the answer.